# My template model destroys the togglePanel()?

Tags: polymer

Why does `t.model = model` break my `p.togglePanel()`?

```
        var t = document.querySelector('template')
        t.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
            t.model = model //<= this breaks my togglePanel?
            var p = document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel')
            p.togglePanel() //<= does not work see above
        })
```

My model looks like this and is needed to configure my polymer table. Note that the table itself works, its the `togglePanel()` that stops working.

```
        var data = [
            {fruit: 'apple', alice: 4, bill: 10, casey: 2, average: 5.3, total: 16 },
            {fruit: 'banana', alice: 0, bill: 4, casey: 0, average: 1.3, total: 4 },
            {fruit: 'grape', alice: 2, bill: 3, casey: 5, average: 3.3, total: 10 },
            {fruit: 'pear', alice: 4, bill: 2, casey: 8, average: 4.6, total: 14 },
            {fruit: 'strawberry', alice: 0, bill: 14, casey: 1, average: 5, total: 15 }
        ]

        var columns = [
            {name:'fruit', cellTemplate: 'fruitsTemplate'},
            {name:'alice'},
            {name:'bill'},
            {name:'casey'},
            {name:'average'},
            {name:'total'}
        ]

        var model = {
            data: data,
            columns: columns
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I was overwriting too much model stuff.

```
    var t = document.querySelector('template')
    t.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
        t.model.data = data
        t.model.columns = columns
        var p = document.querySelector('core-drawer-panel')
        p.togglePanel()
    })
```

This could potentially be a design problem if every webcomponent uses the same model to configure itself?